# throw new NullPointerException in php

Tags: php, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I have a question: how to throw a new Exception of type NullPointer in PHP?

I want to do something like this (in my TryException.php file):

```
public function getValue($stringKey) {
    if($this->result[$yellow] !== NULL)
    {
        return $this->result[$yellow];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("The \"$yellow\" does not exist");
    }
}
```

But when I catch the NullPointerException (in the main.php file) I cannot do that (it does not go in the catch statement):

```
try
{
    $config->getValue('arcshive')
    echo 'ok';
}
catch (NullPointerException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

If I throw a new Exception (and I catch it) (not NullPointer) it works properly.

How can I do?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NullPointerException is an own class of yours extending the PHP Exception class? If so this should work.

```
$var = null;

try {
    if ($var !== NULL) {
        echo 'return $this->result[$yellow]';
    }
    else {
        throw new NullPointerException('The $var does not exist');
    }
} catch (NullPointerException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I made some corrections to your code (Variable names, code limiters), with the use of standard Exception it works as expected:

```
<?php

class Config
{
    private $result;

    public function getValue($stringKey)
    {
        if (isset($this->result[$stringKey])) {
            return $this->result[$stringKey];
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("The \"$stringKey\" does not exist");
        }
    }
}

$config = new Config();
try {
    $config->getValue('arcshive');
    echo 'ok';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Or you add the missing `NullPointerException` class:

```
<?php

class NullPointerException extends Exception 
{
    public function __construct(string $message = "", int $code = 0, \Throwable $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct('NullPointerException: '.$message, $code, $previous);
    }
}

class Config
{
    private $result;

    public function getValue($stringKey)
    {
        if (isset($this->result[$stringKey])) {
            return $this->result[$stringKey];
        }
        else {
            throw new NullPointerException("The \"$stringKey\" does not exist");
        }
    }
}

$config = new Config();
try {
    $config->getValue('arcshive');
    echo 'ok';
}
catch (NullPointerException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. I think was not very clear.

Comment: I see but there still is no `NullPointerException` class. See [Reserved Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php), [SPL Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php)

Comment: @user3563844 Added new examples.